# question involving double sequence of real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, measure-theory

I'm trying to do the following problem.
[image]

I'm working on section 2.5 (product measures) of Folland's Real Analysis book. This problem doesn't come from the book, though. For this problem, I'm considering letting $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)=(Y, \mathcal{N}, \nu)= (\mathbb{N}, \mathcal{P} (\mathbb{N}) , \lambda)$, where $\lambda$ is the counting measure. Any ideas on how to do this? Thank you.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution №1**

Recall the following two theorems.

> **Theorem 1.** Let $(X,M,\mu)$ and $(Y,N,\nu)$ be $\sigma$-finite measure spaces, then
>   $$
> \int_X\left(\int_Y f(x,y)d\nu(y)\right)d\mu(x)
> =\int_Y\left(\int_X f(x,y)d\mu(x)\right)d\nu(y)
> =\int_{X\times Y} f(x,y) d(\mu\otimes \nu)(x,y)
> $$
>   for any $f\in L_1(X\times Y,M\otimes N,\mu\otimes \nu)$.
>
> **Theorem 2.** Let $(X,M,\mu)$ and $(Y,N,\nu)$ be complete $\sigma$-finite measure spaces and let $f:X\times Y\to\mathbb{C}$ be a measurable fnction such that
>   $$
> \int_X\left(\int_Y |f(x,y)|d\nu(y)\right)d\mu(x)<+\infty
> $$
>   then $f\in L_1(X\times Y,M\otimes N,\mu\otimes \nu)$.

Now we return to the original problem. Let $X=Y=\mathbb{N}$, $M=N=\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ and $\mu=\nu=\lambda_{\mathbb{N}}$, then $M\otimes N=\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N})$ and $\mu\otimes \nu=\lambda_{\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}}$. Consider function $f:\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{C}:(m,n)\mapsto a_{mn}$. Since $M\otimes N=\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N})$ it is measurable. From assumption $\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_{mn}|$ it follows that we can apply theorem 2 to get $f\in L_1(\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N},\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})\otimes\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}),\lambda_{\mathbb{N}}\otimes\lambda_{\mathbb{N}})$. Now from theorem 1 we have equality of repeated integrals, which for our particular case translates to 
$$
\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty a_{mn}
=\sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_{mn}
=\sum\limits_{m,n=1}^\infty a_{mn}
$$

**Solution №2**

Denote $x_k=k^{-1}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $x_0=0$ and define the set $X=\{x_k: k\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup\{x_0\}$. Consider
$$
f_m(x_0)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_{mn}\qquad
f_m(x_k)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^k a_{mn}
$$
Since the only limit point of $X$ is $x_0$ and $\lim_{x_n\to x_0}f_m(x_n)=f_m(x_0)$, then for each $m\in\mathbb{N}$ the function $f_m:X\to\mathbb{C}$ is continuous. From assumption it follows that for all $x\in X$ we have $|f_m(x)|\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_{mn}|$
By Weirstrass $M$-test the series $f(x):=\sum_{m=1}^\infty f_m(x)$ is uniformly convergent on $X$. Since $f$ is uniform limit of continuous functions, it is also continuous. Therefore
$$
\sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_{mn}
=\sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty f_m(x_0)=f(x_0)
=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty} f(x_k)
=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty f_m(x_k)
=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty \sum\limits_{n=1}^k a_{mn}\\
=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\sum\limits_{n=1}^k\sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty  a_{mn}
=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty  a_{mn}
$$